# I want to do a left round corner using jquery.corner()

Tags: jquery, jquery-corner

I want only to round the left corners of a div using `jquery.corner()`

Any ideas on getting it done.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round is the default, so to round just the left corners, do the following:

```
$(".selector").corner("left");
```

Comment: Could I do a 2px rounded corner?

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAA IE....... it works fine with ff and chrome, IE is getting showing up white corners inthe background

Comment: To do 2px: `$(".selector").corner("left 2px");`. No idea why you've got a white background in IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('yourSelector').corner('style tl bl');
```

read [docu](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html) for more information (`Choose Your Corner`)

Comment: This is the same doc thats available on the jquery.corner doc website, the blevel left works, but it does not show the rest of the div